# libuv: What is uv_setup_args function?

Tags: node.js, libuv

While reading node.js's source code, I came across this:

```
// Hack around with the argv pointer. Used for process.title = "blah".
argv = uv_setup_args(argc, argv);
```

I have not found any documentation on the function on [libuv docs](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/), as if it didn't even exist. I also checked if it was defined elsewhere in node.js code; it isn't.

Can anyone enlighten me on what it does? Also, could you point me to the documentation, if it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it gets the arguments to the program (in this case, your node process):

http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/misc.html?highlight=uv_setup_args#c.uv_setup_args

The syntax is extremely similar to many C programs that have a main function like:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

The argc variable typically holds the argument count, while argv is the argument vector -- the actual string values passed in (on the command line, for example).